# Is it possible to create a Beam pipeline with multiple windowing needs

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to think of how to architect some data pipeline needs, and I simply want to know if the following is possible:

- Can I create an Apache Beam pipeline that can stream data fully real time while also aggregating into windows? Specifically, I would like to:

  1. Read data in from a Pub/Sub subscription.
  2. Send that data onward immediately to a BigQuery table, as is.
  3. Create an Apache Beam window of, say, 5 minutes.
  4. Aggregate that same data read in from the Pub/Sub message (with some other light transformations).
  5. Write the aggregated/transformed data into a different BigQuery table.
  6. As an always-on streaming pipeline process.

---

I know that I can do this in other ways.  For instance, I can create 2 dataflow jobs / pipelines that listen to the same subscription. (Or would it be better to have 2 separate subscriptions listening to the same topic?)  I can also create a subscription for the dataflow job, then another subscription (to the same topic) that just pushes to BigQuery immediately.

But if I could have one set of code -- and therefore one CI/CD job to monitor -- to accomplish both, it simplifies what we need to maintain, and it would be much preferred.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes that should be possible. You just need to make sure to copy the message within the pipeline, because once you exposed it to the BigQuery sink, it is no longer available for your aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. For writing in BigQuery without using a window, you will need to [use `method` equal STREAMING_INSERTS or STORAGE_WRITE_API (maybe with `use_at_least_once` set to `True` for even lower latency, but with risk of duplicates)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery).

For the rest of the pipeline, you just need to have two branches. Something like this:

```py
msgs = p | "Read from P/S" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubsub(...)
dictionaries = msgs | "Transform to dict with some schema" >> ...
dictionaries | beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(...,method=STORAGE_WRITE_API, use_at_least_once=True,...)
dictionaries | beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(size=300)) | ...  # (aggregate, write to another BigQuery table, etc)
```